# Guardar Excel en Base 64 A Excel Angular6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

Tengo un servicio de Springboot que envía al front un **Excel en base64**, no puedo enviar el Excel directamente por políticas de empresa...

Mi servicio envía:

```
{
 "file": "UEsDBBQACAAIAE6ROU/kSK2vGAEA.........etc"
}
```

Y con Angular6 recojo, decodifico la base64 y lo guardo en formato Excel:

```
this.data.getFile(endPoint).subscribe( 
          data => {          
                     const myfile= atob(data.file);
                     const blob = new Blob([myfile], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
                     saveAs(blob, 'myfile.xlsx'); 
                  } );
```

El contenido de myfile después de atob es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después se guarda el fichero. Finalmente cuando voy abrirlo me da error, dice que el fichero está corrupto.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme ? muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Tienes una cantidad de preguntas donde todo gira sobre resolver problemas que no deberían existir... ¿Has pensado en cambiar de empresa? ;-). Hablando en serio, tienes el problema de que con `atob` transformas base64 a "UTF-16", que son dos bytes por caracter, pero Blob necesita un array de bytes. Puedes mirar esto: https://codeday.me/es/qa/20181204/10667.html

Comment: jajajajaa, muchas gracias, voy hacer eso de array de bytes, muchas gracias tío!

Answer (score 2):

Solución :)

```
public base64ToBlob(b64Data, sliceSize=512) {
let byteCharacters = atob(data.file);
let byteArrays = [];
for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}
return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
}
```